# How can I link third party libraries for Android NDK?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, armadillo

I would like to integrate the "Armadillo" library into my Kotlin and C++ native module project; however, I am encountering difficulties with the linking process. The CMakeLists.txt file is structured as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)
project("nativelib")
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/armadillo/include)
add_library(armadillo SHARED IMPORTED)

add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
        # List C/C++ source files with relative paths to this CMakeLists.txt.
        nativelib.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}
        # List libraries link to the target library
        android
        log
        armadillo
        )
```

And the error is like the below:

```
Task :nativelib:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
C/C++:   IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target "armadillo" configuration
C/C++:   "Debug".
C/C++: CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
C/C++:   IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target "armadillo" configuration
C/C++:   "Debug".
C/C++: CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

The error is not limited to arm64-v8a; it also extends to armeabi-v7a, x86, and x86_64 architectures.

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target "armadillo" configuration
  "Debug".


CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  IMPORTED_LOCATION not set for imported target "armadillo" configuration
  "Debug".
```

I am a beginner in Android NDK development, and I require the Armadillo library for my project. Despite attempting to use the set_target_properties function, I have not been successful in its implementation.

Comment: Do you have a build of the library? You've told cmake that armadillo is an external library but you've not told it anything else